# SVN :- Bash script to create a branch from trunk with limited files

Tags: bash, svn, branch, trunk

I am trying to create a Bash to create a branch from trunk. But i need to take care that some of files will not be a part of new branch, it should be in trunk only.

Please help me on this if any hint is there for this.

Comment: You might wanna consider switching to git, because this feature is built in.

Comment: Which are the files not required? Do you have a list of them?

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

- Create branch with specific files or directories. Note that `svn copy` command can take file or folders like: `svn copy <dir_to_be_branched> <branch_path>`
- Create branch with all files and then delete files/folders that are not required.

Comment: But there are about 300 files/folders need to be delete and this is very difficult to delete them manual so better to create script.

Any idea plz.

Comment: @SunnyThakur Can't you branch only parent folder?

Comment: I need to create a branch of the files and folders available under trunk,but the files/folders which are not needed to branch should not be copied. So i tried to create a script which will remove the unwanted files and folder and will copy to branch....
Currently SVN doesn't support this feature.